# Implement OAuth 2.0 in ColdFusion API

Tags: oauth, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

We have a coldfusion API which we want to be accessible with OAuth2.0 Access Token Functionality with ADFS.
I am unable to find any library related to OAuth Access Token Validation against a certificate or expiry status.

Comment: might want to dip into java for this one.  See https://oltu.apache.org/

Comment: Are you using `<cfoauth>` ?

Comment: @JamesAMohler No, i am using a simple POST Request using CFHTTP. I have the token, but i cannot validate the token against a client key or a certificate.

Comment: @CorySilva How to include JAVA libraries or call methods inside CFC

Comment: Here are a couple of references: [Java Integration Guide](https://cfdocs.org/java) and [Enhanced Java integration in ColdFusion](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html). I'm sure there are a lot more if you do some searches.

Comment: @Miguel-F thanks a lot for the links. I have my .java file, now i am unable to figure out how to call the methods of my java code from Coldfusion

Comment: Edit your question to include the code you are trying and how it is not working (any errors, stack traces, etc).